# QrCodeDetector on Opencv.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm trying to implement a QrCode detector web application using Opencv.Js
For function like `findcountour`, `GaussianBlur`, all is fine but seems like  `cv.QRCodeDetector()` is missing.

```
 let detector = cv.QRCodeDetector()
```

gives

> cv.QRCodeDetector is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It is included in the version I am currently using (4.5.2). Try updating your OpenCV version.

Answer (score 0):

it has became a constructor, so add keywords new like this

```js
const decoder = new cv.QRCodeDetector();
```